# Generics in enum

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I have a data base that can hold strings and integers as values.
When I go trough the data base I want to add each data slot with the contents from the DB.

I've decided to make a collector class that can accept either int or string and I would like to create a enum like this:

**Haxe code:**

```
enum Either<A,B>
{
    Left( v:A );
    Right( v:B );
}
```

For example A could be int and B - string.

Is this possible to do in C# or what would be the best approach to mimic this functionality: keeping strong types (no dynamic variables) to have compiler type-check.

**EDIT**:

I cannot use Tuple since it has no support in Unity3D

Comment: How it is different from  `Tuple<int,string>` or `Tuple<int?,string>`? Sample usage may clarify your goal...

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear about what you want to achieve? I don't understand the reason for this intended design.

Comment: Probably, Dictionary<int, String> is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to have generic enum in a way you described. But what stops from creation of your your own Tuple implementation?

```
public class Tuple<TLeft, TRight> {
    public TLeft Left { get; set; }
    public TRight Right { get; set; }
}
```

If you need serialization support which is pretty often demanded in unity3d, decorate your class with `SerializableAttibute`. Anything in your hands up to investigation of internals of the native .NET Tuple and copying of some useful parts.

Answer (score 0):

An enum is basically just a collection of constants.  Each constant has an identifier, which should be a friendly name, that you can use in code and a numeric value is used under the hood.  As such, the answer to your question is "no".

That said, if you have an enum value then you can call its ToString method to convert it to a String containing the name of the identifier.  I think that you can also cast it as an int or whatever numeric type you specified in the type declaration.  The Enum class also has sone static methods that will convert the other way and more besides.

Answer (score 0):

Note the person doesn't seem to be asking for a Tuple(a type that holds several types like a c style struct but without names), but a [Tagged Union/Sum type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union).

A Tuple has one of each type, a tagged union holds only one value of 2 or more types.

The example he gave is a haxe enum which is not like a c# enum(basically names for a number).

From http://haxe.org/ref/enums

> Note:
>   Haxe Enums behave very similarly to tagged unions, enabling the specification and capture of every "case" of a given method result. Since all Enum states must be specified in switch statements, this makes them valuable in completely defining the behavior of a given method, as well as ensuring that these behaviors are handled.

If you want to make sure every case is always handled don't implement the single Action Run method in the class below.

Also you may want to avoid the name Either as Either(with left/right) is frequently used **specifically** for a union of an error or a result(with left being an error or right being a result.

here is one implementation of a 2 member union.

You might also want a copy of this for 3,4,5 member union with the same name

```
public sealed class Union<A,B,C> : IEquatable<Union<A,B>>
public sealed class Union<A,B,C,D> : IEquatable<Union<A,B,C,D>>
public sealed class Union<A,B,C,D,E> : IEquatable<Union<A,B,C,D,E>>
```

in the pattern of the one below

```
[Serializable()]                
public sealed class Union<A,B> : IEquatable<Union<A,B>>
{
        private enum TypeTag{ A, B};

        private Union ()
        {
        }

        private A AValue;
        private B BValue;
        private TypeTag tag;

        public static Union<A,B> CreateA (A a)
        {
                var u = new Union<A,B> ();
                u.AValue = a;
                u.tag = TypeTag.A;
                return u;
        }

        public static Union<A,B> CreateB (B b)
        {
                var u = new Union<A,B> ();
                u.BValue = b;
                u.tag = TypeTag.B;
                return u;
        }

        public U SelectOn<U> (Func<A, U> withA, Func<B, U> withB)
        {
                if (withA == null)
                        throw new ArgumentNullException ("withA");

                if (withB == null)
                        throw new ArgumentNullException ("withB");

                if (tag == TypeTag.A)
                {
                        return withA (AValue);
                } 
                else if (tag == TypeTag.B) 
                {
                        return withB (BValue);
                }

                throw new InvalidOperationException ("Unreachable code.");
        }

        public void Run (Action<A> actionIfA, Action<B> actionIfB)
        {
                if (actionIfA == null)
                        throw new ArgumentNullException ("actionIfA");

                if (actionIfB == null)
                        throw new ArgumentNullException ("actionIfB");

                if (tag == TypeTag.A) 
                {
                        actionIfA (AValue);
                } 
                else if (tag == TypeTag.B) 
                {
                        actionIfB (BValue);
                }
        }

        public void Run (Action<A> actionIfA)
        {
                if (actionIfA == null)
                        throw new ArgumentNullException ("actionIfA");

                if (tag == TypeTag.A) 
                {
                        actionIfA (AValue);
                }
        }

        public void Run (Action<B> actionIfB)
        {
                if (actionIfB == null)
                        throw new ArgumentNullException ("actionIfB");

                if (tag == TypeTag.B) {
                        actionIfB (BValue);
                }
        }

        public override string ToString ()
        {
                if (tag == TypeTag.A) 
                {
                        return "Type A" + typeof(A).ToString() + ": " + AValue.ToString();
                } 
                else if (tag == TypeTag.B) {
                        return "Type B" + typeof(B).ToString() + ": " + BValue.ToString();
                }

                throw new InvalidOperationException ("Unreachable code.");
        }


        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                int result = tag.GetHashCode();
                        if (tag == TypeTag.A) {
                                result = (result * 397) ^ (AValue != null ? AValue.GetHashCode() : 0);
                        } else if (tag == TypeTag.B) {
                                result = (result * 397) ^ (BValue != null ? BValue.GetHashCode() : 0);
                        }
                return result;
            }
        }

        public override bool Equals (object other)
        {
                if (other is Union<A,B>)
                {
                        return this.Equals((Union<A,B>)other);
                }
                return false;
        }

        public bool Equals (Union<A,B> other)
        {
                if (this.tag != other.tag) 
                {
                        return false;
                }
            if (tag == TypeTag.A) 
            {
                        return this.AValue.Equals(other.AValue);
                } 
                else if (tag == TypeTag.B) 
                {
                        return this.AValue.Equals(other.AValue);
                }
                return false;
        }
}
```

example usage:

```
var i = Union<int,string>.CreateA(5);
var s = Union<int,string>.CreateB("Fre");
s.Run(actionIfA: n => { Console.WriteLine("1.number*3  is " + n*3); },
                actionIfB: str => { Console.WriteLine("1.uppercase string is " + str.ToUpper()); });
var r = i.SelectOn(withA: n => "2.number*3  is" + n*3 , withB: str=> "2.uppercase string is" + str.ToUpper());
Console.WriteLine(r);
s.Run(actionIfA: n => { Console.WriteLine("3. number*3  is " + n*3); });
s.Run(actionIfB: str => { Console.WriteLine("4. uppercase string  is " + str.ToUpper()); });
i.Run(actionIfA: n => { Console.WriteLine("5. number*3 is " + n*3); });
Console.WriteLine("does i equals s:" + i.Equals(s));
```

if you want to use it in a more imperative/slightly faster/less safe way
make the tag and Values public(or make the tag public and use Get(A/B/C/D/E)OrThrow methods to enable better exceptions if you use in the wrong fashion) and use if/else or switch on it to use AValue/BValue(/CValue/DValue/EValue if you are using a 3/4/5 tuple). Note this make it impossible to force you to handle all states and makes it more likely you will mess up and use the wrong type.